# How to load another url in surfaceview mediaplayer android?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview

When I open the app first I can load the Url to the surface view but later on itemclick when i try to laod another url it cannot load.

My code to load url to player is :

```
  private void setChannelLink(String url){

    SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
    videoHolder.addCallback(this);
    player = new MediaPlayer();

    try {

        player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        player.setDataSource(this, Uri.parse(url));
        player.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        player.setOnErrorListener(this);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

when I try to load another url i am doing player.stop() and player.reset() before calling this method.. What am i missing?

Comment: By looking at the above code we cannot predict the error.Please post the entire code and the logcat.where is the surfaceCreated() method??

Comment: `   @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        try {

            player.setDisplay(holder);
            player.prepareAsync();

        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }`